# Save lists to csv as columns in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have three list that I'd like to write to .csv file, where each list is written as a column. Example:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [0,1,4,9,16]
z = [1,1,1,1,1]
```

The file would then have the structure:

```
0 0 1
1 1 1
2 4 1
3 9 1
4 16 1
```

I don't mind if what the delimiter is. Tabs, commas etc is fine.

I've tried something like:

```
numpy.savetxt('file.csv',zip(x,y,z))
```

But this just creates a 1D list with alternating values of x, y and z, I thought it would work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i, j, k in zip(x, y, z):
        writer.writerow((i, j, k))
```

**Result:**

```
>>> with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
...     print(csvfile.read())
...
0,0,1
1,1,1
2,4,1
3,9,1
4,16,1
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks

Comment: @RichardHall You're welcome, don't forget to accept it as answer to your question :)

Comment: Just did, was waiting for the 10min timer :)